# Generic element of Kronecker product

Tags: matrices, inner-products

How can we find the generic element of the Kronecker product of two matrix: Let $A=(a_{ij})_{{1\leq i\leq n}, {1\leq j\leq p}}$ and $n\times p$ matrix and $B=(b_{ij})_{{1\leq i\leq m}, {1\leq j\leq q}}$ and $m\times q$ matrix. The Kronecker product of $A$ and $B$ is defined as:
$$ 
A\otimes B=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11}B  & \cdots & a_{1p}B  \\
\vdots &  & \vdots \\
a_{n1}B  & \cdots & a_{np}B \end{array} \right)
$$
So, $A\otimes B$ is an $nm \times pq$ matrix. How we can point out the generic element $(A\otimes B)_{k\ell}$ for $k\in \{1, \dots, nm\}$ and $ \ell \in \{1, \dots, pq\}$ using the  Euclidean division of $k$ and $\ell$.

A lot of thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i was also stuck into this problem since few days during my research and finally got the solution..
The generic element of a kronecker product of **A** (LxL) and **B** (MxM) can be expresses as follows

**(A kron B)_{i,j} = A(ceil(i/M, j/M))*B((i,j))M**

where ((.)) is mod operation

hope this would help.

cheers,
alam zaib